# How to go through the link in html?

Tags: javascript, html, django, http, hyperlink

I have a little question. in my html page i have a text box, where i can type `anything i want`. When i press ENTER i want to go through the next url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?request=anythingiwant`Is there eny methods to do this in html code?? Here the code

```html
{% extends 'finder/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
 <div class="container">
        <div class="image"></div>
  <h2>Super Search Engine</h2>
        <p>I'm searching for:</h2>
        <input type="text" id="inp" onkeypress="return runScript(event)"> 
    </div>

    <script>
  function runScript(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          //var tb = document.getElementById("scriptBox");
          //eval(tb.value);
          //return false;
          alert("kekos");
          $.ajax({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/',
           data: {
               'request': document.getElementById('inp').value,
           },
           success: function(data){
               $scope.key = data['key'];
               $scope.isAuthorized = true;
               $window.alert('You are logged in.');
           },
           error: function(data){
               $window.alert("Something was wrong.");
           },
         })
      }
  }
 </script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You're looking for `<form>`.

Comment: A form element and submit button?

Comment: It should be `type: "GET"` instead of `method: "POST"`.

Comment: @Barmar tryed, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reload from the new URL, assign to `window.location` instead of sending an AJAX request.

```
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.location = "http://127.0.0.1:8000:/search/?" + encodeURIComponent(event.target.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am correctly understanding your question . You can do this:

```
function runScript(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                var tb = document.getElementById("np").value;
                //eval(tb.value);
                //return false;
                alert("kekos");
                $.ajax({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?request='+tb,
                    success: function(data){
                        $scope.key = data['key'];
                        $scope.isAuthorized = true;
                        $window.alert('You are logged in.');
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        $window.alert("Something was wrong.");
                    },
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `scriptBox`? Why do you send the request data in both the URL parameter and the `data:` option?

Comment: if you want to load this new url than you should use window.location as written by barmar.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need send your text input value as parameter to other page you can make it with **form action**([description at W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp))

Exmaple:

```
<form method="get" action="/search/">
  <input type="text" name="request" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

If you don't need submit button, just trigger **submit** event on your form with JS(onkeydown, for example)